# Problema na consulta com join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Estou com um problema na consulta para gerar um relatório. Fiz um JOIN da tabela pedidos (que vai tirar o relatório) com a tabela de clientes e produtos. Até então tudo funcionou, mas ele praticamente não mostra todos os pedidos, só mostra o primeiro. No momento eu tenho cerca de 3 pedidos relacionados com as tabelas. Vejam o código:

```
SELECT pedidos_id,
       pedidos.cliente_id,
       pedidos.produto_id,
       clientes.nome AS nome_cliente,
       produtos.nome AS nome_produto,
       pedidos.data,
       pedidos.frete,
       pedidos.quantidade,
       pedidos.total,
       SUM(pedidos.total) as sub_total
  FROM pedidos
       INNER JOIN clientes ON pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.clientes_id
       INNER JOIN produtos ON pedidos.produto_id = produtos.produtos_id
 ORDER BY clientes.nome
```

O que será que está errado no código?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faltou o `GROUP BY pedidos_id`, não?

Comment: Cara ele até funciona mas o problema é o sub-total. Ele não soma os valores do total de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Você precisa ser um pouco mais claro na sua pergunta. Quais os dados que você espera no final? Como você pretende obter o subtotal?

Comment: O sub-total tem que ser da coluna total. Veja eu tenho 3 registros e preciso que ele faça o relacionamento com as outras duas tabelas de clientes e produtos e cada pedido possui um total. O sub-total seria a soma de todos os pedidos da coluna total.

Comment: Cara....se você quer fazer um relatório, o total é somado no próprio relatório e nao no select... o que está usando pra fazer o relatório ?

Answer (score 2):

Verifique que possui colunas com valores diferentes... obs: campos em AMARELO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
você não pode utilizar uma função de agregação `SUM` com valores diferentes nas linhas.

OBS: Neste caso seria eliminada a coluna `SUM` e faria o somatório por dentro do relatório.

Answer (score 1):

Faça um *Group by* de todos os campos não agregados, do jeito que está ele está somando todos os pedidos num único registro:

```
SELECT pedidos_id  
     , pedidos.cliente_id  
     , pedidos.produto_id  
     , clientes.nome AS nome_cliente  
     , produtos.nome AS nome_produto  
     , pedidos.data  
     , pedidos.frete  
     , pedidos.quantidade  
     , pedidos.total  
     , SUM(pedidos.total) as sub_total  
  FROM pedidos  
 INNER JOIN clientes ON pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.clientes_id  
 INNER JOIN produtos ON pedidos.produto_id = produtos.produtos_id  
 GROUP BY pedidos_id  
        , pedidos.cliente_id  
        , pedidos.produto_id  
        , clientes.nome
        , produtos.nome
        , pedidos.data  
        , pedidos.frete  
        , pedidos.quantidade  
        , pedidos.total  
 ORDER BY clientes.nome
```

Comment: Deu certo mas preciso calcular o total da coluna total de todos os registros.

Comment: Qual banco você está usando?

Comment: mysql workbench

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Tente fazer uso do WITH ROLLUP logo atrás da instrução GROUP BY. Ficaria *GROUP BY PEDIDOS.PEDIDOS_ID WITH ROOLUP*, ou se quiser dum modo mais tradicional, somente com *subSelect*.